# bash shell error: "no such file or directory"

Tags: bash, virtualenv

I am trying to install [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) wrapper on Ubuntu 14.04. But whenever I start a terminal, I get the error saying bash:

> /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh: No such file
>   or directory.

I also checked the bashrc script by using `gedit ~/.bashrc`, but there is no such line like that. Does anyone know where I am wrong?

Comment: Have you checked other configuration files such as `.bash_profile`, and system-wide versions in `/etc/`?

Comment: Yes I already checked .bash_profile, but it is empty and I dont know how to check /etc/.

Comment: There should be un-hidden global files as `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: Have a look at this source http://chrisstrelioff.ws/sandbox/2014/09/04/virtualenv_and_virtualenvwrapper_on_ubuntu_14_04.html which may assist you with some idea.

Comment: @vembutech I checked the above link, but it did not help.I already add path of my virtualenvwrapper.sh in my bashrc. But I didn't found any path like I described above in my question. Whenever I tried source ~/.bashrc, it gives the above error

Comment: @ElvinAslanov there is no such lines in bash.bashrc

Comment: You can debug with `bash --login -x` although the output will be rather copious and hard to comb through.  Maybe run with [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) so you get the output in a file you can easily search etc.

Comment: Unless you have something very secret in your `.bashrc` (most people don't) you might just want to upload it to https://pastebin.com/ and link to it from here.

Answer (score 24):

In my case, I had previously installed virtualenvwrapper using `apt-get install virtualenvwrapper` and later uninstalled it using `apt-get remove virtualenvwrapper`, which left the 'configuration' file `/etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper` behind. This bash completion definition was sourced by bash (it had nothing to do with my .bashrc) and caused the error message.

The solution was to run:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualenvwrapper
```

Which purged  all files related to virtualenvwrapper. The reason I uninstalled it was to use pip's version instead (more up-to-date), which can be installed globally using:

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Comment: I had this issue in sublime text 3 on OSX when building a script and to solve I just installed it via pip as your command states above. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Worked on Kubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 23):

I just had the same problem on Linux Mint.

The following file was causing the issue:
/etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper

I made a backup (just in case) and deleted it, and everything seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Worked for me (+1).

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu (+1)

Comment: Great tip, thanks. Don't leave the backup of this file in the `bash_completion.d` folder or it will not work as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Following [these instructions](http://railslide.io/virtualenvwrapper-python3.html), I found that the error occurred when sourcing the virtualenvwrapper bash script, i.e.:

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

The script references the file `/etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper` as pointed out by arcticfeather.

Open up the script using the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper
```

This is where the non-existent file is being referenced. Simply replace `/usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh` with `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh` and you should be good to go!

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Extension to virtualenv for managing multiple virtual Python environments (*virtualenvwrapper*) in Ubuntu 14.04 from the Ubuntu Software Center or from the terminal using the following command:

```
sudo apt install virtualenvwrapper
gedit .bashrc
```

Add the following line to the end of .bashrc.

```
source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Save the changes to .bashrc and close gedit. Source your .bashrc for the changes to take effect.

```
cd 
source .bashrc
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the answers work like for myself, just create an empty file at the location giving out an error and shebang to it.

In the case of OP:

`sudo nano /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh`

and write:

`#!/bin/bash`

Save it and try to open terminal again, did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

I hope it help someone, in my case i was trying to create the virtualenv being inside a **screen** (*screen -S whatever*), the solution was closing the screen and executing the virtualenv command again being outside.